# Retrieve a specific col name from a panda df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a panda df with one row and 1700 columns. Now I have a specific value say 10 that is present in one of these 1700 columns. How do I retrieve that column name with the specific value =10?

Comment: `df.iloc[0].eq(10).idxmax()`?

Comment: Is guaranteed always exist value `10` ? If not ouput should be error, None, something else? E.g. if test value 1000 - this value not exist in any column.

Comment: I understood that the value is indeed present: "***I have a specific value** say 10 **that is present** in one of these 1700 columns*". Otherwise it's possible to check that `df.iloc[0][found_idx]` is indeed `10`

Comment: added to answer what I think.

Answer (score 0):

If exist value at least one value solution from comment working well - get first match:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,10,5,7]]).add_prefix('col')
print (df)
   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     1    10     5     7
```

Select first row for Series, compare 10 and use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
col = df.iloc[0].eq(10).idxmax(axis=1)
print (col)
col2
```

If test and not exist got wrongly first column, not bug, but feature:

```
col = df.iloc[0].eq(100).idxmax(axis=1)
print (col)
col0
```

Possible solution is test if exist at least one value - here is `None` instead first column:

```
m = df.iloc[0].eq(100)
col = m.idxmax(axis=1) if m.any() else None
print (col)
None
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value exists, the simplest in my opinion would be to use `df.iloc[0].eq(10).idxmax()`

If there is a chance that the value is absent and you want to avoid returning the first value, use:

```
s = df.iloc[0]
s[s.eq(10)].first_valid_index()
# 'col2'   # using @jezrael's example

s[s.eq(9)].first_valid_index()
# no output
```